# Equations in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor

I have to put a sum in a fraction and I want to keep the "big" form for the sum. But when I insert the sum in the numerator the sum becomes "small". How can I do to keep its original form?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Because Word assumes you want the "small" form, it automates that for you once you hit another key after typing in the fraction. To keep the fraction in it's "big form", select Ctrl+Z (undo) immediately after it it changes it, to undo the automation.